# How can I update from elementary os loki to newer version Juno

Tags: release-loki, updates, release-juno

I am looking for a way to update my current  machine running elementary os loki to juno. How do I do that

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is no way to upgrade from 0.4 Loki to 5.0 Juno. Juno is still in beta and is not currently a stable release. You can download and compile the beta via the official website through the following link:

https://developer.elementary.io/#beta

Alternatively, the Ubuntu fan site OMG!Ubuntu! has a direct download link at the bottom of a news article for the Juno beta that contains an ISO image for the beta:

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/elementary-os-juno-beta-download

Comment: Is there possibly gone be a mechanism to update to Juno later, once the official release is done???

Comment: No previous version has had a clear upgrade path.

Comment: This is a major disappointment tho, I will just switch to Mint or something now. I had such high hopes with this OS

Answer (score 0):

there is a few "backdoors" you could try, there is no direct path admittedly. try updating the repo's and doing a 'apt dist-upgrade' may yield some results, or may brick your system, one of them, I've not played around with it i just installed JUNO